# Can I rescue the girl AND collect the bank info?

Tags: deus-ex-mankind-divided

So I've been fooling around in Deus Ex: Mankind Divided, and I decided to already break into the VersaLife vault after finding their vault keycard in a bank office early on. I figured this would be a plot point later on, so I wanted to see if I could get a head start.

> I did this by breaking into the vault via the parking lot opposite the bank and finding an entrance through a ventilation duct into the bank vaults

When I was in the VersaLife vault, I opened the safe, read everything there was to read, took everything there was to take, hacked the computer emails, etc.

Now later on, I'm forced to make a choice between:

- Go on a rescue mission
- Break into the VersaLife container at the bank

In the previous game (DX: Human Revolution) when you've accidentally achieved a goal before it's needed, Jensen has a conversation branch that effectively bypasses the mission. This did not happen this time.

Given that I've already broken into the VersaLife container, I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve both outcomes here?

Answer (score 5):

According to IGN's Wiki pages for the [Bank Mission](http://www.ign.com/wikis/deus-ex-mankind-divided/Mission_12:_The_Heist) and the [Rescue Mission](http://www.ign.com/wikis/deus-ex-mankind-divided/Mission_11:_Confronting_the_Bomb-maker), at a certain point in both missions, the other one will be effectively cancelled, making it impossible to do the other.

The point of no return in the bank mission is:

> If you truly intend to leave Nomad and his daughter, moving up to the top floor will effectively cancel the other mission, and Allison will perish.

The point of no return in the rescue mission is:

> Climbing up to the second floor will effectively cancel Mission 12: The Heist. Be sure this is what you want to do before proceeding.

It appears there use to be a [glitch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xm99aAma1VU) that involved jumping in and out of bounds to do the rescue mission without losing the bank heist mission, but it has been patched as of the 1.04 update.

Comment: This game had a few tough choices. Good answer!

Answer (score 1):

I went back to a previous save and ran both missions. Even though I had broken into the VersaLife vault already, the key thing you need from the vault for the storyline is revealed in a cut scene.

It is impossible to discover without triggering the mission, so no, you cannot complete both missions even if you do one early.

Comment: I'm curious, was their something wrong with my answer that made you post your own?  They're pretty alike.

Comment: Your answer stated when the missions cancel each other out, which was not what I _actually_ asked - I wanted to know if you could achieve both outcomes by doing things out of order, which you could sometimes do in previous Deus Ex games. That said it wasn't a _bad_ answer, which is why I left it and answered myself. Also my answer explicitly stated _why_ it is impossible to achieve both outcomes.